# Amazon VPC Availability

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc

We are trying to expand our reliability setup using VPC in us-west-1. The 'a' and 'b' AZs work fine, but when I try to create subnets on 'c' it just fails with the message:

```
Value (us-west-1c) for parameter availabilityZone is invalid.
Subnets can currently only be created in the following availability zones:
  us-west-1b, us-west-1a.
```

Is this a transient failure or are there just only two VPC-enabled AZs in that region? If the latter, is there a list somewhere with how many AZs in each region are VPC-enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Availability Zones grow over time, Amazon's ability to expand them can become constrained. If this happens, they might restrict you from launching an instance in a constrained Availability Zone unless you already have an instance in that Availability Zone. Therefore, your account might have a different number of available Availability Zones in a region than another account.

Use the [describe-availability-zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-availability-zones.html) command to describe your Availability Zones within the region.

Comment: I got an error about a subnet being in a constrained zone when creating an ALB, but describe-availability-zones listed all zones including the subnet's zone.

Answer (score 2):

The letters are mostly meaningless.

Example:

**Account 1** creates an instance in us-east-1a
**Account 2** creates an instance in us-east-1b

**Both instances** are in the **same availability zone**, they just *appear* as different zones to the user.
It is just a way to represent that an instance is in a separate AZ from another.

---

**Source:** I was informed of this during AWS Systems Operations training in Sydney.

Comment: [Regions and Availability Zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-regions-availability-zones) doc confirms this: "To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones for a region, we independently map Availability Zones to identifiers for each account. For example, your Availability Zone us-east-1a might not be the same location as us-east-1a for another account. Note that there's no way for you to coordinate Availability Zones between accounts"

Comment: Yes, thats why I was careful to words it that "two of three". The psychological load balancing is irrelevant except for making the error message even harder to search for.